# What's the proper name for taking out single key:value from object and storing it as variable?

Tags: javascript

In javascript you can do things like:

```
const person = {name: 'Tom', surname: 'Smith'};
const { name } = person
```

and then you will have `name` equal to `'Tom'`.

The question is - how is this "operation" of taking `name` from `person` and storing it as variable called?

Comment: It's "destructuring," in that case "destructuring assignment." From [*de-*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/de-) (*remove from*) and [*structure*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/structure) (*organization of parts as dominated by the general character of the whole*). The *de-* part is *slightly* a misnomer, it doesn't *remove* `name` from `person`, it just extracts it. But the terminology was well-established long before JavaScript. There's also parameter value destructuring and argument destrcuturing (same thing, different contexts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called `destructuring assignment`. Please refer to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)